# Extracting text between curly braces in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of text like following

`1. Foobar { abc } ( Explanation - Foo { cde } - Count - 5301435 ) 2. Foobaz { memo } ( Explanation - baz {bleh } - Count - 13946664 )`

And I want to extract
`abc` and `memo` in the above string.
I have the regex as follows [link [here]](https://pythex.org/?regex=%7B(%3F%3A%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D)*%7D&test_string=1.%20Foobar%20%7B%20abc%20%7D%20(%20Explanation%20-%20Foo%7B%20cde%20%7D%20-%20Count%20-%205301435%20)%0A2.%20Foobaz%20%7B%20memo%20%7D%20(%20Explanation%20-%20baz%7Bbleh%20%7D%20-%20Count%20-%2013946664%20)&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

essentially `{(?:[^{}])*}`
But it captures everything `(returns abc, cde, memo, bleh)`

Comment: so do you want the first elements on every line?

Comment: so you just want the first instance in each string?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Yes..

Comment: @DawitAbate Ah.. I see the source of confusion.. Actually its not each line.. but rather a blob that I get..

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Ah.. I see the source of confusion.. Actually its not each line.. but rather a blob that I get. I edited the input to reflect that

Comment: so you want text nested in curly braces that **isn't** nested in parentheses?  can you explain the requirement completely?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I want the output of above to be abc and memo... which are like the "first" instances in each numbered list.. I was thinking like regex to match `{` on left and '} (' on right to do this.. as this will capture abc and memo.. but unable to come up with regex

Comment: This is quite tricky to do with a regex and fairly easy to do with a stateful parser.  I recommend to ditch the regex approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
\d+\.[^{]*{\s+([^}]+)\s+}
```

and get the captured groups.

- `\d+\.` matches one or more digits, followed by a `.`
- `[^{]*` matches upto the next `{`, `{\s+` matches `{`, followed by one or more whitespaces
- the captured group, `([^}]+)` matches upto next `}`
- `\s+}` matches one or more whitespaces, followed by `}`

**Example:**

```
In [48]: blob = '1. Foobar { abc } ( Explanation - Foo { cde } - Count - 5301435 ) 2. Foobaz { memo } ( Explanation - baz {bleh } - Count - 13946664 )'

In [49]: re.findall(r'\d+\.[^{]*{\s+([^}]+)\s+}', blob)
Out[49]: ['abc', 'memo']
```

Answer (score 7):

I would keep it simple.

```
import re

s = '1. Foobar { abc } ( Explanation - Foo { cde } - Count - 5301435 ) 2. Foobaz { memo } ( Explanation - baz {bleh } - Count - 13946664 )'

s_without_parens = re.sub('\(.+?\)','',s)

text_in_brackets = re.findall('{(.+?)}',s_without_parens)

text_in_brackets

[' abc ', ' memo ']
```

So you can nest that as `re.findall('{(.+?)}',re.sub('\(.+?\)','',s))`, but I find it helpful to break it into logical steps.

Answer (score 2):

Simple `re.findall()` approach:

```
import re

s = '1. Foobar { abc } ( Explanation - Foo { cde } - Count - 5301435 ) 2. Foobaz { memo } ( Explanation - baz {bleh } - Count - 13946664 )'
result = re.findall(r'\{ ([^{}]+) \} (?=\()', s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['abc', 'memo']
```